# Regex to remove any line-breaks that appear between quotes in a CSV file

Tags: php, regex, csv

I am trying to find a regular expression that will match any line breaks that are between double quote seperated strings in a CSV file.

I am able to identify the strings between quotes using this regex:
`(["])(?:\\.|[^\\])*?\1`

I am able to identify line breaks using this regex:  `(\r\n|\r|\n)`

But I'm not sure how to 'combine' the two to get the expression that I need.

The expression should match only line breaks that exist between double quotation marks.

Comment: so are the strings separated with line breaks or with double quote. an example would be good

Comment: Why combine them? Grab the strings with one and do a replace with the other.

Comment: fgetcsv can handle this

Comment: There might be something to do with Lookahead and Lookbehind.  But cannot debug a solution right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@fyroc suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55345831/regex-to-remove-any-line-breaks-that-appear-between-quotes-in-a-csv-file#comment97416692_55345831), combine the two regular expression separately, like this:

```
<?php
$testString = <<<EOF
a,b,c,d,"test
test2
test3",zzz
zz,yy,vv,"a
b
"
uuu,ttt,"xyz",zzz
aaa,bbb,ccc
ddd,"","a","zz"
xyz,abc,"a
b
c
"
"
a,c,d,"
dadasda"
EOF;

function remove_eol($matches) {
    //var_dump($matches);
    return preg_replace('/\R/', '', $matches[0]);
}

$testStringWithoutEnclosedEol = preg_replace_callback('/(["])(?:\\\\.|[^\\\\])*?\1/', 'remove_eol', $testString);

?>
<?php var_dump($testStringWithoutEnclosedEol); ?>
```

Take notes that I changed this regex

```
(\r\n|\r|\n)
```

To simply

```
\R
line break: matches \n, \r and \r\n
```

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php

And I had to add extra \ in the string passed to preg_replace_callback...

Comment: perfect!  I was considering doing something like this but wasn't sure if the regex could handle on its own.  Thank you!

Comment: If it works for you, please accept my answer. ;-)